# How can I make location not equal None

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When I try to print or call location it says that it returns None. How can I make it so it returns the location of where I click?

```
import turtle
line = turtle.Turtle()

def click_location(x,y):
    line.up()
    line.setpos(x,y)
    line.down()
    return line.pos()


location = window.onclick(click_location)
```

Comment: `window.onclick()` just registers a function to be called when a click occurs.  It cannot possibly return the location of a click, because the click hasn't happened yet.  Anything you want to happen in response to a click, you must put inside (or called by) the registered function.

Answer (score 0):

With a minor alteration (two lines added, and one altered), it worked for me:

```
import turtle
line = turtle.Turtle()
window = turtle.Screen()

def click_location(x,y):
    line.up()
    line.setpos(x,y)
    line.down()
    #return line.pos()
    print(line.pos())

location = window.onclick(click_location)
print(location)
turtle.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick handler can't return anything.  You can display the x, y values, you can set a global to the x, y values, or you can act on the x, y values.  But you can't return them.

Here's an example that displays them:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ('Arial', 36, 'normal')

def clicked_location(x, y):
    turtle.undo()  # erase previous coordinates
    turtle.write((x, y), align="center", font=FONT)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.write(turtle.position(), align="center", font=FONT)

screen = Screen()
screen.onclick(clicked_location)
screen.mainloop()
```

This code:

```
location = window.onclick(click_location)
```

won't do what you want as `onclick()` always returns `None` and the event whose location you seek hasn't happened yet.